Problemas al imprimir valor en innerHTML
Estoy teniendo problemas para imprimir un valor en javascript.
codififico como JSON el siguiente array
$response = ['producciones' => $getProducciones, 'output' => $output];
echo json_encode($response);

Para imprimirlo hago lo siguietne, pero me dice que no hay datos. Cuando en la consola si que me está mostrando datos.
content.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.producciones);
content2.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.output);

